# Excel não consigo ler a celula no código VB

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

```
x.Range("A1:z1").Select
x.Goto Reference:="R2C4"
verificaCel =     x.ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1

if verificacel then
```

Não estou conseguindo ler a célula especifica na planilha do excel, no qual vou enviar os dados para um banco de dados.

Comment: Para verificar algo vc deve colocar o que precisa ser verificado, exemplo `verificacel = "teste"`... dê um `debug.print verificacel` para verificar o valor que tem nessa variável.

Comment: Este valor que aparece na verificacel "=SUMIF(Matriz!C[6],RC[-4],MATRIZ!C[5])" ...e o que deveria aparecer é um valor "314,82"

Comment: Então ao invés de usar o `x.ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1` use `x.ActiveCell.Value`

Comment: Deu certo \o/\o/\o/\o/

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!

Comment: Como o problema foi resolvido, postei a resposta para marcar como resposta e deixar como referência para outros colegas.

Answer (score 1):

Para ler o valor da célula deve-se usar `.value` ou `.text` se aplicável. Usando `.FormulaR1C1` o resultado será a fórmula da célula. Segue correção abaixo:

```
verificaCel = x.ActiveCell.Value
```

Comment: Obrigado Evert. Como dizem.. "simples assim" rs

Comment: Marcos marque como resposta clicando no "V" cinza ao lado da resposta para ficar verde. Isso significa que a resposta resolveu seu problema. Valeu